# simulate pulling marbles from a bag without replacement (efficiently)

Tags: python, random

I need to simulate a hypergeometric distribution (fancy words for sampling elements w/o replacement) in python.

The setup: There is a bag filled with *population* many marbles. There are two types of marbles, red and green (in the following implementations the marbles are represented as True and False). The amount of marbles to be pulled out of the bag is *sample*.

The following are two implementations I have come up with for the problem, however they both start degrading in speed at population > 10^8

```
def pull_marbles(sample, population=100):
    assert population % 2 == 0
    marbles = [x < population / 2 for x in range(0,population)]
    chosen = []
    for i in range(0,sample):
        choice = random.randint(0, population - i - 1)
        chosen.append(marbles[choice])
        del marbles[choice]
    return marbles
```

This implementation is very readable and follows the setup of the problem clearly. However, it must create a list of size *population*, which seems to be the bottleneck.

```
def pull_marbles2(sample, population=100):
    assert population % 2 == 0
    return random.sample([x < population / 2 for x in range(0, population)], sample)
```

This implementation uses the random.sample function in hopes of speeding things up a bit. Unfortunately, it does not address the underlying bottleneck of generating a list of length *population*.

**EDIT:** By mistake, the first code sample returns marbles, which makes this question ambiguous. So unambiguously, I want the code to return the number of red marbles and green marbles that were "pulled." Sorry for the confusion - I will keep the original incorrect version of pull_marbles up however to not make already existing answers seem invalid.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @senshin Uh, I'm not really that familiar with the statistics going on behind this problem (I've been asked to do this for a friend who wanted to teach stats to kids). Can you maybe elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: @JaneDoe Ah, sorry, on second thought, my proposed idea isn't useful here. Rejection sampling on discrete distributions is apparently tricky, so yeah, never mind me.

Comment: If the bottleneck really is that it has to create that `chosen` list of size `population`… well, you're not actually using that list for anything at all, so why not just not bother creating it? Remove the two lines with `chosen` in them, and your code will have the same effect, and remove your perceived bottleneck.

Comment: Also, are you sure that all those `del marbles[choice]` calls (each of which takes O(N) time) aren't hurting you? Using a multiset, or just a pair of numbers, would alleviate that. And it would also save a bunch of storage, too. Since all white marbles are identical and all black marbles are identical, why keep around a list with millions of each?

Comment: You're creating two lists of millions of marbles, where all of the red marbles are identical, and all of the green marbles are identical. Those lists together take O(N) storage, and you have O(M) deletions that each take O(N) time. But if you just used an efficient multiset instead of a list, that would take O(1) storage, and O(M) deletions that each take O(1) time. And none of your code would need to change except for the type you use. This is effectively the same thing all of the answers are doing, except they just explicitly deal with pair of numbers that would underlie the multiset impl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of representing your bag by a list just use two integers counting the red and the green marbles.  Each pulling is done by checking a random number of range `(0..red+green)` for being less than `red`.  If it is, a red is pulled, so decrease `red`, otherwise a green is pulled, so decrease `green`.

This way you will have to do all pulls iteratively, but I guess that shouldn't be a problem.  *But* there might be optimizations I can't think of right now for pulling vast amounts of numbers without having to do this iteratively.

```
def pull_marbles(sample, population=100):
  red = population / 2
  green = (population+1) / 2  # round up just to ensure red+green == population
  for i in range(sample):
    choice = random.randint(1, red + green)
    if choice <= red:  # red pulled
      red -= 1
    else:
      green -= 1
  return (red, green)
```

Answer (score 2):

This takes time proportional to `sample` (instead of to `population`).  While you didn't say so, your code appears to assume that there are an equal number of each color of marble in the bag to begin with.  The code here follows that, but can be easily fiddled to use some other assumption:

```
def pull_marbles(sample, population=100):
    from random import random
    assert population % 2 == 0
    chosen = []
    nTrue = population / 2.0
    nTotal = float(population)
    for _ in xrange(sample):
        if random() < nTrue / nTotal:
            chosen.append(True)
            nTrue -= 1.0
        else:
            chosen.append(False)
        nTotal -= 1.0
    return chosen
```

Comment: The OP's code returns original marbles - chosen, while yours returns chosen. This is trivial to fix, of course.

Comment: @abarnert, that depends on which one of the OP's two code samples you're looking at.  I'm following the second one, which makes more sense ;-)

Comment: But I still don't like the idea of using lists of Booleans for representing the bag contents (or the pulled ones, for that matter).  It's a stupid waste of memory.

Comment: @Alfe, I'm answering the OP's question.  If you want an answer to a different question, ask your own question ;-)

Comment: Nicely put ;-)  But then at least during your computation you could be cleverer and in the end just spit out what the OP wants (`return [True] * red + [False] * green` or similar).

Comment: @Alfe, I have no way to know whether the OP wants the returned list to reflect the order of selection, so I'm giving them something as close as possible to what `pull_marbles2()` **does** without consuming insane time.  The only complaint they had about their own code is speed, so my presumption has to be that they're happy with everything else it does.

Comment: Hi. I did make a bit of an oopsie in the first code sample and I do apologize for it; it is my fault. The intent of my code is to return the number of red marbles, and green marbles selected.

Comment: @JaneDoe, that's fine.  You have several answers now that will do that efficiently, so pick one and move on ;-)  [http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/235416](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/235416)

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_sample(sample_size ,population_size):
   reds=population_size/2
   greens = population_size/2
   marbles = 
   sample = []
   for i in range(sample_size):
       red_prob = 1.0*red/(red+green)
       grn_prob = 1.0*green/(red+green)
       #the second argument is the probabily of picking one color or another
       choice = numpy.random.choice([0,1],p=[red_prob,grn_prob])
       sample.append(choice)
       if choice == 0: reds -= 1
       else: greens -= 1
   return sample
```

you dont need a whole list...
just randomly pick between your variables with a probability that matches teh theoretical list

on a side note

```
marbles = [x < population/2 for x in range(population)]  # SLOW
#takes  69 us with population of 1k
#takes memoryerror with population of 10^8 (2.5 seconds for 1/8th of the 10^8 population)
marbles = [False]*(population/2) + [True]*(population/2) #much FASTER!!!
#takes 8.6 us for population of 1k
#takes 272 ms for half the list so about 544 ms total
marbles = [True,False]*(population/2) #fastest ...
#2.19 us with population of 1k
#329 ms with population of 10^8
```

Comment: technically, you don't need any of this; there are libraries for it. But the way I understand it is that the purpose is to explicitate the logic underlying the final distribution for didactic purposes. For that purpose, it may be useful to have a series of implementations, from one that explicitly follows the steps as youd perform them by hand, to one that is a bit more generous with the dose of abstraction. From that perspective, the only problem with the original code is that the list datastructure does not have O(1) insertion/deletion.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the list is unnecessary. Try something like this:

```
def pull_marbles(sample, population=100):
    assert population % 2 == 0
    marbles = [x < population / 2 for x in range(0,population)]
    total_chosen = 0 # number of times you sampled it. this would always == population but included for clarity
    true_chosen = 0 # number of samples that were True
    for i in range(0,sample):
        choice = random.randint(0, population - i - 1)
        if marbles[choice]: true_chosen += 1
        total_chosen += 1
        del marbles[choice]
    return true_chosen, total_chosen
```

This returns two integers, of which the ratio is the number that came up True

Comment: Oh, didn't realize it was the `marbles` list. I just assumed you built that for demonstration but were trying to avoid the `chosen` list

Answer (score 0):

My two bits - similar to others.  Calculate the probability of picking each color then compare those to a random number - accumulate choices.

```
import random
from operator import itemgetter

least_probable = color = itemgetter(0)
most_probable = probability = itemgetter(1)

def select(pop, samp):
    assert pop % 2 == 0 and samp < pop
    choices = (random.random() for _ in xrange(samp))
##    choices = (random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) for _ in xrange(samp))
##    choices = (random.triangular() for _ in xrange(samp))
    num_red = num_green = 0    
    total_red = total_green = pop / 2.0
    for choice in choices:
        p_red = total_red / pop
        p_green = total_green / pop
        marbles = [('RED', p_red), ('GREEN', p_green)]
        marbles.sort(key = probability)
        if choice <= probability(least_probable(marbles)):
            marble = color(least_probable(marbles))
        else:
            marble = color(most_probable(marbles))
        if marble is 'RED':
            num_red += 1
            total_red -= 1
        else:
            num_green += 1
            total_green -= 1
        pop -= 1
##        print marbles, choice, marble
    return ('RED', num_red), ('GREEN', num_green)

for thing in (select(100000000, 1000) for _ in xrange(20)):
    print thing
```